# what is avurlasset work and simplyfie this mehtod?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, avurlasset

```
 AVURLAsset* audioAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:assetURL options:@{AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey:@YES}]; 
 // audio asset url  create object and specifies its method....
```

this audio asset can get value in only second?

I want to know how above code works and role of AVURLAsset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AVURLAsset` is a subclass of `AVAsset`. `AVAsset` is used to get information about the asset such as metadata (like track titles, author, composer, and so on). The "asset" is usually a sound or video file.

In the example you have given, you are creating an `AVAsset` from a URL, and you are specifying that you want precise duration and timing. Because of that option, when you ask for the duration, there may be a significant amount of work required for the `AVAsset` method to compute a precise time. This is clearly stated in the Apple documentation. The documentation also suggests that you usually do not need the precise duration and timing.

Answer (score 1):

The (no-)difference between `AVAsset` and `AVURLAsset` as of 2022-12-08:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avurlasset

*This class is a concrete subclass of `AVAsset`. When you create an asset as shown below, the system creates and returns an instance of `AVURLAsset`.*

```
let url: URL = // A local or remote asset URL.
let asset = AVAsset(url: url)
```